# Regex that matches string that occurs after another string

Tags: regex

Lets say I have the string `"hello hello hello goodbye"`

How would I create a Regex expression in python that matches only the last `hello` found before the `goodbye`?

Comment: What environment are you using regex in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"hello(?= goodbye)"` would do the job, that last part is a 'positive lookahead' that requires the enclosed text to immediately follow for the match to be considered valid.

EDIT: With the clarification that there might be extra text between 'hello' and 'goodbye', this should work: `".*(hello).*?goodbye"`.  Note that in this case the found 'hello' is group 1, rather than the entire match, so the code to make use of this regex would be a bit different.  The key point is that the `.*` at the start is a greedy match; it initially matches the entire string, and then backs up character by character in an attempt to find a 'hello'.  A consequence of this is that if you have multiple hello/goodbyes in your string, the regex only matches the very last one; you couldn't use `re.findall()` (for example) to find them all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How could I use this to find the last hello even if there is text between it and the goodbye?